# Getting "argument type mismatch" during MVEL expression evaluation

Tags: java, function, evaluation, mvel

For the following code snippet I am getting the error "argument type mismatch".
If I use the commented line, it works fine.

Can some one explain the reason for this behavior?

Is there a way I can get the first expression itself evaluated?

```
VariableResolverFactory functionFactory = new MapVariableResolverFactory();    
Object value = MVEL.eval("def StringValueWithLength(str) { int myLen = str.toString().length(); return String.valueOf(str) + \":\" + myLen; }; StringValueWithLength(\"qwert\");", functionFactory);
//Object value = MVEL.eval("def StringValueWithLength(str) { return String.valueOf(str) + \":\" + str.toString().length(); }; StringValueWithLength(\"qwert\");", functionFactory);
System.out.println("Value : " + value);
```

Comment: Getting compiler error with latest version of mvel, which version are you using? `MapVariableResolverFactory` expects a `Map` argument

Comment: JDK 1.8 and mvel2-2.3.1.Final.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug/limitation in MVEL, I debugged the MVEL code.

The argument type in the `return` statement is wrongly detected by MVEL which is actually a `String` but detected as `int`

```
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(int)
```

for the expression

```
Object value = MVEL.eval("def StringValueWithLength(str) { int myLen = str.toString().length(); return String.valueOf(str) + \":\" + myLen; }; StringValueWithLength(\"qwert\");", functionFactory);
```

and thrown

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch.
```

Below expressions works as you expected

```
String expr = "def StringValueWithLength(str) { int myLen = str.length(); return String.valueOf(str) + \":\" + myLen; }; StringValueWithLength(\"qwert\");"; // removed toString
```

or

```
String expr = "def StringValueWithLength(str) { int myLen = str.toString().length(); return str + \":\" + myLen; }; StringValueWithLength(\"qwert\");"; // removed String.valueOf
```